# Why an @Input angular passed as array is updated outside without send Emit using EventEmitter?

Tags: angular

I do not understand why Angular updates one property `this.list` modifies inside the component without using the **@Output** EventEmitter, I noticed that occurs only when I passed an array.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Item } from "./models/item";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "Hello";
  list: Item[];

  constructor() {
    this.list = [
      {
        text: "Link 1"
      },
      {
        text: "Link 2"
      }
    ];

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Itens", this.list);
    }, 11500);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Note I'm not using two-way binding `[()]`

```html
<menu [items]="list"></menu>
```

The component:

```js
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Item } from "../../models/item";

@Component({
  selector: "menu",
  styleUrls: ["./menu.component.css"],
  templateUrl: "./menu.component.html"
})
export class MenuComponent {
  @Input() items: Item[];

  constructor() {
    // after 10 seconds change the data
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.items.push({
        text: "Link 3"
      });
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

[Reproduce example](https://codesandbox.io/s/two-way-binding-ye4v8?file=/src/app/components/menu/menu.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array to the child component, via an Input, as it's a non [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) value, the child component will receive a reference to the array defined in the parent component. Therefore we can mutate the array from everywhere.

The behavior is not related to Angular because it's Javascript fundamentals.

Comment: like @serrulien said and because default [Change Detection](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/) gets trigger by `setTimeout` function so the parent's view will be updated, It won't work if you use change detection `OnPush` in the child component

Comment: by the way, you should only manipulate `@Input` properties inside `ngOnInit`, not inside the `constructor`